# How to show all Git tags in TFS web interface

Tags: git, tfs

Using TFS 2017 15.117.26714.0

I have a bunch of tags that I see in Tortoise Git

[image]

I see only the first tag in the "Code" section of TFS web interface.

[image]

What makes it weirder is those tags were created by TFS.  They are build tags, created by the TFS builds.  So it's not a question of the tags not being synced.  Why are they not showing up in the web interface?  I checked two different user accounts.

[Probably this is just a bug in TFS, but I tried submitting a support ticket and Microsoft support was, as ever, useless.  Maybe someone knows a workaround?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was those tags weren't on the server.  I cloned a new copy of the repository and didn't see the tags in there either.  So I pushed up the tags from my original repository, and now I see them.  No idea how those tags got deleted from the server's repository.  Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

The tags are shown on the right hand side of the UI as shown. I am using the same version of TFS as you

> Version 15.117.26714.0

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  Why doesn't your view show the Author, Authored Date and Pull Request Columns?  Mine does, and that doesn't seem to be configurable.

Comment: It does show Author, Authored Date, Pull Request & Build. I just didn't include it in my screen grab

Comment: if you can see it on your UI now, please mark it as answer

Comment: Nope, it's definitely not there.  i only see the most recent tag.  I see the same problem on other projects, some build tags show up, others do not.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

The version should be TFS 2017 update2. My environment has updated to TFS 2017 update3 (`Version 15.117.26912.0`). I tested that and everthing works as expected.

They should be displayed there if the tags were created by the TFS builds automatically. However you can have a try to sync the repo or with command `git push origin --tags`, then clean the caches for your browser to check that again.

Also try to check this in other clients.

If that still not work, just try upgrading to  TFS 2017 update3. Whatever it works for me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try update 3 as soon as it goes RTM (as of 11/1/2017 it's just a RC).